# Flutter check if a class have a contain a key

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter,
My project work when I don't use my class but I want to use class so I change my project for use that and I have some problems.

*In my code how to check if the parameter that I use in my function as KeyReference exist in my class ?
And how to use my parameter keyReference for search in my list of user ?*

**This is my class :**

```
class User{
  int type;
  String name;
  num index;
 
  User({
    this.type,
    this.name,
    this.index,
  });

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map){
    type = map['type'];
    distance = map['name'];
    hausse = map['index'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['distance'] = this.name;
    data['hausse'] = this.index;
  }
```

And this is my function :

```
static List<User> getListItemsEquality(var value, String keyReference, List<User> items)
  {
    //**************** Error  ****************//
    if(items == null)
    {
      throw MyException.noData();
    }

    items.forEach((item) {
      // =================================================================================
      // I have an error on this The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'User'.
      //=================================================================================
      if(!item.containsKey(keyReference)){ 
        throw MyException.parameterNotExist();
      }
    });

    //**************** Script  ****************//
    // =================================================================================
    // The getter 'keyReference' isn't defined for the type 'Charge'. 
    //=================================================================================
    return items.where((c) => (c.keyReference == value)).toList();
  }
```

Comment: Did you fix this?